# Maven dependency error when using <resources>

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

My project has a dependency on hibernate-core. Everything works fine when I deploy the project to JBOSS from Eclipse.

When I add a resource entry in my **pom** in order to filter a **persistence.xml** file I start getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session` exception during the deploy.

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

As soon as I remove this  tag, the deploy runs normally

Answer (score 0):

I doubt when you remove this xml it removes some xml files which are when present at runtime asking this class to load

Simply add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

make version as your app's compatibility

Comment: I've already have this dependency declared in my pom, as stated in the first phrase of my question :). Also, I'm not removing the xml file, I'm filtering it in order to "inject" a maven property in it.

Comment: it doesn't add to that jar or one of its dependency to classpath then

Comment: The thing is that when I remove the <resources> bit from my pom the deploy works just fine, so there is nothing wrong with that dependency alone.

Comment: I assume at runtime you are seeing this error, that clearly means it is failing to find either that class or class it is dependent on

Comment: Yes, that is clear to me as well. What is not clear is why this error only happens when I use the <resource> tag

Comment: I think because it interprets those xml files differently when present at runtime